# Ajax on form submit help

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

This works if you actually click the button:

```
$form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'image_button',
    '#src' => drupal_get_path('module', 'contact_block') . '/images/send_button.png',
    '#ajax' => array(
        'callback' => 'contact_block_ajax',
        'method' => 'html',
        'event' => 'click',
        'wrapper' => 'content-block-content-main-form',
        'progress' => array(
            'type' => 'throbber',
            'message' => '',
            ),
        ),
);
```

If, however, someone presses `enter` on another field, then the form submits without ajax.  How do I do an ajax form submission?

Comment: The above code actually works for what I was looking for... my mistake (and hours spent)!

Comment: please close the question if you found the answer!